# Logstash CSV output format, with file records in different rows

Tags: csv, logstash

I am using logstash to do a transformation from a CSV file to another, but in the output file all data is on a unique row.

I am using a **row_sep** "\r\n" in the following way:

`

```
output {
    csv {
    path => "/tmp/BCHARTS-MTGOXUSD-output2.csv"
    fields => ["Date","Open"]
    csv_options => {"col_sep" => "," "row_sep" => "\r\n"}
    } 

}
```

`

[image]

What should be the way to have the data in different rows?

Answer (score 0):

The [split filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html) can create multiple events from one input string.